# Training TensorFlow models

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

When I started training the TensorFlow models using model_main_tf2.py I got this:

```
TensorFlow Addons (TFA) has ended development and introduction of new features.
TFA has entered a minimal maintenance and release mode until a planned end of life in May 2024.
Please modify downstream libraries to take dependencies from other repositories in our TensorFlow community (e.g. Keras, Keras-CV, and Keras-NLP). 

For more information see [.](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2807)
```

and the training process stopped at less than 10 minutes.

I tried this code.

```py
# Run the command below from the content/models/research/object_detection directory
"""
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=path/to/pipeline.config
MODEL_DIR=path to training checkpoints directory
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=50000
SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1

python model_main_tf2.py -- \
  --model_dir=$MODEL_DIR --num_train_steps=$NUM_TRAIN_STEPS \
  --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=$SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES \
  --pipeline_config_path=$PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH \
  --alsologtostderr
"""

!python model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path=/mydrive/customTF2/data/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.config --model_dir=/mydrive/customTF2/training --alsologtostderr
```

This is the output.

```
2023-05-14 22:08:38.006027: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_addons/utils/tfa_eol_msg.py:23: UserWarning: 

TensorFlow Addons (TFA) has ended development and introduction of new features.
TFA has entered a minimal maintenance and release mode until a planned end of life in May 2024.
Please modify downstream libraries to take dependencies from other repositories in our TensorFlow community (e.g. Keras, Keras-CV, and Keras-NLP). 

For more information see: []((https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2807)) 

  warnings.warn(
2023-05-14 22:08:42.686271: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:47] Overriding orig_value setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
I0514 22:08:42.706633 140183536396096 mirrored_strategy.py:374] Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
I0514 22:08:42.888072 140183536396096 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
I0514 22:08:42.888273 140183536396096 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16: False
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:563: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W0514 22:08:43.068961 140183536396096 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:563: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/gdrive/MyDrive/customTF2/data/train.record']
I0514 22:08:43.236968 140183536396096 dataset_builder.py:162] Reading unweighted datasets: ['/content/gdrive/MyDrive/customTF2/data/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/gdrive/MyDrive/customTF2/data/train.record']
I0514 22:08:43.237378 140183536396096 dataset_builder.py:79] Reading record datasets for input file: ['/content/gdrive/MyDrive/customTF2/data/train.record']
INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1
I0514 22:08:43.237509 140183536396096 dataset_builder.py:80] Number of filenames to read: 1
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0514 22:08:43.237593 140183536396096 dataset_builder.py:86] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:100: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.deterministic`.
W0514 22:08:43.254249 140183536396096 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:100: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is desired, use `tf.data.Options.deterministic`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:235: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
W0514 22:08:43.275877 140183536396096 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:235: DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.map()
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
W0514 22:08:49.218866 140183536396096 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
W0514 22:08:52.275295 140183536396096 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: sample_distorted_bounding_box (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`seed2` arg is deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W0514 22:08:54.703264 140183536396096 deprecation.py:364] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:1176: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py:124: The name tf.keras.optimizers.SGD is deprecated. Please use tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD instead.

W0514 22:08:58.218291 140183536396096 module_wrapper.py:149] From /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py:124: The name tf.keras.optimizers.SGD is deprecated. Please use tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD instead.

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:452: UserWarning: `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11. To update it, simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
  warnings.warn(
I0514 22:09:10.429069 140178526795520 api.py:459] feature_map_spatial_dims: [(40, 40), (20, 20), (10, 10), (5, 5), (3, 3)]
^C
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I started training the TensorFlow models using model_main_tf2.py I got this:                                   `TensorFlow Addons (TFA) has ended development and introduction of new features.
TFA has entered a minimal maintenance and release mode until a planned end of life in May 2024.
Please modify downstream libraries to take dependencies from other repositories in our TensorFlow community (e.g. Keras, Keras-CV, and Keras-NLP). 

For more information see [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2807) `